# HTML Audio not looping over if clicking the same button repeatedly

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Consider this code:

```
function playAudio() {
    var sound = new Audio("audio/mgs5.mp3");
    if (!sound.play()) {
        sound.play();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a button with a sound to playback. Problem is, if I press the button another time, it will overlap a second playback ontop of the current playback already running.

How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function playAudio() {
    var sound = new Audio("audio/mgs5.mp3");
    if (!sound.play()) {
        sound.pause()
        sound.currentTime = 0
        sound.play();
    }
}
```